# Ansible shell module empty response

Tags: ansible

When i execute the command "who am i" using ansible's shell module, i get an empty response, i can't figure out why ?

```
  hosts: server1
  remote_user: devops
  become: true
  tasks:
    - name: print current user
      shell: who am i
      register: userr
    - debug:
        msg: "{{ userr.stdout }}"

[root@ansible test]# ansible-playbook test.yml 

PLAY [test playbook] ********************************************************************************************************************************

TASK [Gathering Facts] ******************************************************************************************************************************
ok: [server1]

TASK [print current user] ***************************************************************************************************************************
changed: [server1]

TASK [debug] ****************************************************************************************************************************************
ok: [server1] => {
    "msg": ""
}

PLAY RECAP ******************************************************************************************************************************************
server1                    : ok=3    changed=1    unreachable=0    failed=0
```

Comment: shell is a valid ansible module yes. i do not want to replace it with the command module because i plan to use piping afterwards. but even using the command module, i get the same empty output.

Comment: @Jesse_b Have a look here: http://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/shell_module.html I use the `shell` module a lot as I find it more flexible than `command`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The reason i think is that ansible is not using a login shell to execute the command. So the command is not displaying anything.

```
If you replace: 

who am i

with:

su - anotheruser; who am i
```

You should see an output.